# Renaming files using their folder's name with bash `find`

Tags: bash, cp

My goal is to find all files named `README.md` in sub-folders, and to copy them in an `output` folder, using the name of their original folder as their new name.

Ok that sounds complicated. Let's see a concrete example:

```
baselines
├── combined_tree_local_conflict_obs
│   ├── README.md
│   └── sparse_small_apex_maxdepth2_spmaxdepth30.yaml
└── global_density_obs
    ├── README.md
    └── sparse_small_apex_expdecay_maxt1000.yaml
```

I want to copy the `README.md` files to the `output` folder with the names `combined_tree_local_conflict_obs.md` and `global_density_obs.md`.

So in the end I'd have:

```
baselines
├── output
│   ├── combined_tree_local_conflict_obs.md
│   └── global_density_obs.md
├── combined_tree_local_conflict_obs
│   ├── README.md
│   └── sparse_small_apex_maxdepth2_spmaxdepth30.yaml
└── global_density_obs
    ├── README.md
    └── sparse_small_apex_expdecay_maxt1000.yaml
```

I don't understand why my bash command doesn't work:

```
$ find baselines -type f -name "README.md" -exec echo output/$(basename $(dirname {})).md \;
output/..md
output/..md
```

(I'm not copying the files yet but just printing their new path to debug the command.)

The find command does work:

```
$ find baselines -type f -name "README.md" -exec echo {} \;
baselines/combined_tree_local_conflict_obs/README.md
baselines/global_density_obs/README.md
```

Extracting the folder name does work:

```
$ echo $(basename $(dirname "baselines/combined_tree_local_conflict_obs/README.md"))
combined_tree_local_conflict_obs
```

But! somehow when I put them together it doesn't work.

I'm not so much interested in how to solve this problem in another way, but rather to understand why my command doesn't work.

Comment: Please, add expected structure

Comment: @GillesQuenot added

Comment: `$(basename $(dirname {}))` runs *before `find` even starts*. It can't possibly operate on the names of the specific files that were found.

Comment: BTW, everything you're doing here is covered in [Using Find](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind).

Comment: Please, don't change the rules when you have 2 answers for next times

Comment: Changing the rules? you mean looking for an explanation rather than a solution?

Comment: Changing the depth of directory after having 2 answers is _changing the rules_

Comment: I didn't change the depth, check the edits. The structure was always the same, i simply made it clearer in the `tree` outputs

Comment: You added `baselines` parent dir that was not existing at the beginning https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62785400/revisions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) explain in comments,

*`$(basename $(dirname {}))` runs before find even starts. It can't possibly operate on the names of the specific files that were found.*

I have some better solutions...

First:

```
cd baselines
```

Then, like this to re-use your code:

```
find . -type f -name "README.md" -exec bash -c '
    echo cp "$1" "./output/$(dirname "$1").md"
' -- {} \;
```

or

```
find . -type f -name "README.md" -exec bash -c '
    for file; do
        echo cp "$file" "./output/$(dirname "$file").md"
    done
' -- {} +
```

Check https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind

or

```
for file in */README.md; do
    echo cp "$file" "./output/$(dirname "$file").md"
done
```

Drop the `echo` command when the output looks good for you (don't try to feed bash `STDIN`).

```
cp ./combined_tree_local_conflict_obs/README.md ./output/./combined_tree_local_conflict_obs.md
cp ./global_density_obs/README.md ./output/./global_density_obs.md
```

Comment: BTW, it probably bears noting that the safe way to run the commands this generates is to reinvoke the script with the `echo` taken off, **not** to pipe the output to `sh` or `bash`. Otherwise, someone with a directory that contains `$(rm -rf ~)` in its name could have a really bad day!

Comment: (though one _could_ also make it generate safe commands; for example, by changing the inner `echo` to something like `printf "cp %q %q\n" "$file" "./output/$(dirname "$file").md"`)

Comment: This uses the full path of the files in the new names, but I only want to keep the name of the directory the files are in! I get `cp baselines/combined_tree_local_conflict_obs/README.md ./output/baselines/combined_tree_local_conflict_obs.md` while i would want `cp baselines/combined_tree_local_conflict_obs/README.md ./output/combined_tree_local_conflict_obs.md`

Comment: @MasterScrat mismatch between your intput structure and your `find` command.

Comment: Ok, that works. I would have preferred a more general solution that doesn't require a `cd` in the directory but this does the job!

Comment: I would have preferred a better description of your question at the beginning ;)

Comment: Fair enough ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), with full regex capabilities to handle the new case of the  parent directory `baselines`:

```
perl -MFile::Find -MFile::Copy -we '
    find({
        no_chdir => 1,
        wanted => sub {
             if (-f && m/README\.md$/) {
                 my $mod = my $file = $File::Find::name;
                 $mod =~ s@.*([^/]+)/.*@output/${1}.md@;
                 print "$file => $mod\n";
                 #copy("$file", "$mod") or die $!;
             }
         }
     }, @ARGV);
' ./baselines/
```

This is in debug mode, to do it for real, remove the `print` command and *uncomment* the `copy()` line.

Answer (score -1):

What about this

```
$ find baselines -type f -name "README.md" -exec echo output/$(dirname {}|sed 's@/@_@/g').md \;
```

Comment: sed: 1: "s@/@_@/g": bad flag in substitute command: '/'

Comment: I think he means `'s@/@_@g'`.

Comment: This can't work: The `$(dirname {}|sed 's@/@_@/g')` command substitution is invoked *before `find` is started*.